Making coconut milk from creamed coconut
I bought a block of creamed coconnut (note this is not coconut cream, but a block of coconut) and want to make coconut milk. I found a few sources that say to make 400ml of coconut milk, dissolve 100g into 400ml of boiling water. But I have 500ml after dissolving, not 400ml. Does anyone have any advice on the right ratio?

The reason you have more volume after is because it isn't actually dissolving (and won't dissolve). Coconut milk is an emulsion (stable mix of oil and water), so both volumes are there when you "dissolve" it.

Thanks. Can you advise how I get 400ml of coconut milk using creamed coconut, like you would get from a can?

You'd need to blend it to make an emulsion - mix the ratios. Looks like it is 1 part coconut to 3 parts water or thereabouts depending on how thick you like your milk. Boiling water will separate the fat from the coconut, so you'd only do that for cooking I think.
